# how to extract year, month and day in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have **csv** files on my **gcs** saved in paths like **/data/yyyy=2020/mm=07/dd=03, /data/yyyy=2020/mm=08/dd=04** etc. I have been trying to find a way to extract the **yyyy, mm, dd** values in the file path so i can use it to populate similar columns in my BigQuery Table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [March 2020](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#March_02_2020) - BigQuery supports loading externally partitioned data in Avro, Parquet, ORC, CSV and JSON formats that is stored on Cloud Storage using a default hive partitioning layout.

By default, when such data loaded from Cloud Storage - Hive partition keys appear as normal columns. There are three modes of hive partition schema detection supported:

- AUTO: Key names and types are auto detected. The following types can be detected: STRING, INTEGER, DATE and TIMESTAMP.
- STRINGS: Key names are automatically inferred with STRING type.
- CUSTOM: Partition key schema is encoded in the source URI prefix.

Meantime, if needed, you can provide a custom partition key schema to name those cols as - for example - year, month, day instead of yyyy, mm, dd

See more about [Loading externally partitioned data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#supported_data_layouts)